# NonlinearModelFit Returns Without Evaluating

Tags: fitting, nonlinear, constraint

When running NonlinearModelFit on certain functional forms, the method just returns the input expression without evaluating. For example:

```
nlm2 = 
 NonlinearModelFit[
  rUnder, {a (t/tl (1 - t/tl)^b)^(1/2)}, {{a, 21}, {b, .5}, {tl, 
    2.17}}, t, Weights -> weightsUnder, 
  VarianceEstimatorFunction -> (1 &)]

Out[1]= NonlinearModelFit[{{1.81593, 20.}, {1.9886, 
   16.6667}, {2.02291, 15.625}, {2.09426, 13.8889}, {2.12865, 
   11.3636}, {2.158, 7.8125}, {2.17323, 7.57576}, {2.18395, 
   4.16667}, {2.1344, 12.5}, {2.08936, 13.8889}, {1.99008, 
   17.8571}, {1.89548, 19.2308}, {1.83101, 19.2308}, {1.7435, 
   21.1795}, {1.7158, 22.7273}, {1.6527, 20.8333}, {1.63489, 
   20.}, {1.616, 20.}, {1.59589, 20.}, {2.04861, 17.3524}, {1.9781, 
   18.2618}, {1.96271, 18.6676}, {1.9468, 18.9353}, {1.93863, 
   19.1374}, {1.81373, 19.9836}, {1.80704, 19.9943}, {1.7933, 
   19.9749}, {1.78147, 19.872}, {1.76925, 20.0654}, {1.78387, 
   20.0318}, {2.04328, 20.1613}, {2.03385, 20.4918}, {1.9062, 
   23.1481}, {1.8732, 25.}}, {a Sqrt[(t (1 - t/tl)^b)/tl]}, {{a, 
   21}, {b, 0.5}, {tl, 2.17}}, t, 
 Weights -> {11.3798, 34.9676, 23.1823, 41.8684, 59.9708, 168.066, 
   246.244, 112.401, 35.5266, 29.2875, 18.9364, 16.1314, 12.3042, 
   49.706, 13.9461, 53.9137, 52.9276, 49.7358, 46.7365, 21.7433, 
   71.1736, 67.3292, 129.239, 15.842, 149.66, 72.7971, 84.6504, 
   82.3477, 68.1859, 24.7328, 105.164, 18.0225, 26.1849, 33.8865}, 
 VarianceEstimatorFunction -> (1 &)]
```

A similar error occurs with `CubeRoot` (not shown for conciseness).

The problem does go away if I put `Abs` around the interior of the root, but this produces an unsatisfactory fit. It also goes away if I use `Re` instead, but breaks again if I change the starting parameter away from `.5` (and indeed does not appear to vary that parameter).

I *could* try using `FindFit` or taking the logarithm of my data, but I don't know how to un-transform the resulting statistical error measures.

Comment: @LouisB gives you the answer below and you might want to look at the following: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139038/what-are-some-common-issues-with-fitting-functions-to-data/139256#139256.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The eighth data point is {2.18395, 4.16667} and the parameter `tl` starting value is 2.17.  So, this data point will give a complex value for the starting parameter values.  A fix is change the starting value of `tl` and add a constraint that `tl` cannot be less than the greatest value of `t` in the data.

Try this:

```
nlm2 = NonlinearModelFit[rUnder,
   {a (t/tl (1 - t/tl)^b)^(1/2),
    tl > Max[rUnder[[All, 1]]]},
   {{a, 21}, {b, .5}, {tl, 2.2}},
   t, Weights -> weightsUnder,
   VarianceEstimatorFunction -> (1 &)];

nlm2["BestFitParameters"]

Plot[nlm2[t],
 {t, Min[rUnder[[All, 1]]], Max[rUnder[[All, 1]]]},
 Epilog -> {Point[rUnder]}]

(*  {a -> 37.8786, b -> 0.600229, tl -> 2.18499}  *)
```