# New user guideline/heuristic to prefer SematicImport over Import?

Tags: import

I am wondering if there is any advice to new users about when/why to use Import over SemanticImport.

I am aware that a [really good summary of fitting data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139038/what-are-some-common-issues-with-fitting-functions-to-data?newsletter=1&nlcode=495758%7C3d59) highlighted that the `Fit[]` command for instance, hasn't been updated since v6 and new learners would probably benefit from defaulting to `LinearModelFit[]` and `NonlinearModelFit[]`.

Does `SemanticImport[]` belong in the same category/rule of thumb?

Comment: `Import` tends to be much faster.

Comment: note: found out SemanticImport tries to form a Dataset object which is often/maybe a better object to do data queries on.

Comment: You can always make a Dataset out of a plain table. What is more valuable to me is the possibility to specify and enforce one datatype for one column with SemanticImport.