# Is it feasible to curve fit to a staircase function?

Tags: functions, fitting, approximation

Taking as a starting point the advice given in this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139038/what-are-some-common-issues-with-fitting-functions-to-data) I am trying to fit data to a staircase function as follows:

```
model = {h (1/2 + ((x - a)/w) - ArcTan[Tan[π (-(1/2) + ((x - a)/w))]]/π), 60 <= a <= 90, 50 <= h <= 150, 50 <= w <= 150};
nlm2 = FindFit[ptsech, model, {a, h, w}, x, Method -> "NMinimize"]
```

but now I'm wondering is it even possible to fit such data to a discontinous function? though it approximates the data as I wish. The problem is that code it not producing correct values for h, w and a even when manually bringing these values close. How can it be modified to work?

```
ptsech={{0, 0}, {30., 0}, {54.366, 0.00901776}, {67.0222, 
0.477768}, {70.7722, 4.22777}, {71.241, 16.884}, {71.25, 
41.25}, {71.25, 71.25}, {71.259, 95.616}, {71.7278, 
108.272}, {75.4778, 112.022}, {88.134, 112.491}, {112.5, 
112.5}, {142.5, 112.5}, {166.866, 112.509}, {179.522, 
112.978}, {183.272, 116.728}, {183.741, 129.384}, {183.75, 
153.75}, {183.75, 183.75}, {183.759, 208.116}, {184.228, 
220.772}, {187.978, 224.522}, {200.634, 224.991}, {225., 
225.}, {255., 225.}, {279.366, 225.009}, {292.022, 
225.478}, {295.772, 229.228}, {296.241, 241.884}, {296.25, 
266.25}, {296.25, 296.25}, {296.259, 320.616}, {296.728, 
333.272}, {300.478, 337.022}, {313.134, 337.491}, {337.5, 
337.5}, {367.5, 337.5}}
```

Comment: the problem is the constraint `50 <= w <= 50`. Change it into e.g. `50 <= w <= 150` and it'll work just fine.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform to be fair to myself the contraints I used were much wider; the 50 was an editing error. So that alone did not actually cause the problem. The solution lies in reducing the data sample which is not obvious and not necessarily the only solution.

Comment: I see. If you edit your post to fix that, I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform okay w fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ptsech = {{0, 0}, {30., 0}, {54.366, 0.00901776}, {67.0222, 
    0.477768}, {70.7722, 4.22777}, {71.241, 16.884}, {71.25, 41.25}, {71.25, 
    71.25}, {71.259, 95.616}, {71.7278, 108.272}, {75.4778, 112.022}, {88.134,
     112.491}, {112.5, 112.5}, {142.5, 112.5}, {166.866, 112.509}, {179.522, 
    112.978}, {183.272, 116.728}, {183.741, 129.384}, {183.75, 
    153.75}, {183.75, 183.75}, {183.759, 208.116}, {184.228, 
    220.772}, {187.978, 224.522}, {200.634, 224.991}, {225., 225.}, {255., 
    225.}, {279.366, 225.009}, {292.022, 225.478}, {295.772, 
    229.228}, {296.241, 241.884}, {296.25, 266.25}, {296.25, 
    296.25}, {296.259, 320.616}, {296.728, 333.272}, {300.478, 
    337.022}, {313.134, 337.491}, {337.5, 337.5}, {367.5, 337.5}};

{xmin, xmax} = MinMax@ptsech[[All, 1]];
```

As pointed out in a comment by AccidentalFourierTransform, the range of `w` should be widened.

```
model = {h (1/2 + ((x - a)/w) - 
      ArcTan[Tan[π (-(1/2) + ((x - a)/w))]]/π), 60 <= a <= 90, 
   50 <= h <= 150, 50 <= w <= 150};

nlm2 = FindFit[ptsech, model, {a, h, w}, x, Method -> "NMinimize"]

(* {a -> 70.8647, h -> 102.825, w -> 112.674} *)

Plot[Evaluate[model /. nlm2], {x, xmin, xmax},
 PlotRange -> {-10, 350},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[3],
   Point[ptsech]}]
```

[image]

Assuming that the near vertical runs are causing the offsets, reduce the data set prior to fitting.

```
ptsechr = Union[ptsech,
   SameTest -> (Abs[#1[[1]] - #2[[1]]] < 1 &)];

nlm2r = FindFit[ptsechr, model, {a, h, w}, x, Method -> "NMinimize"]

(* {a -> 71.5147, h -> 112.658, w -> 113.258} *)

Plot[Evaluate[model /. nlm2r], {x, xmin, xmax},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[3],
   Point[ptsech]}]
```

[image]

The offset has been corrected.